# Viewing Observations Based on the values of two other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on an administrative dataset for a job training program program. And I am trying to visualize/check the number of unique observations (i.e. ***beneficiary_name*** variable) per year, based on the values of a ***start_date*** column for the five-year period of the program.

Specifically, the first year starts on 2012-09-01, and ends on 2013-08-31, the second year starts on 2013-09-01, and ends on 2014-08-31, and so on.

Ultimately, I would like to see how my 93,500 observations are distributed across the years. For instance, one insight I may be able to find is that 90% of observations who are say 30 yrs or younger, joined the program during it's first year, presumably because they are more connected to the workforce and are more aware of government-assistance programs.

Thus far, this is the code that I have tried:

```
teachers_subsidy5 %>%
  mutate(year = NA,
         year = ifelse(date < "1/9/2012", 1, year),
         year = ifelse(date > "1/9/2013" & date < "31/8/2014", 2, year),
         year = ifelse(date > "1/9/2014" & date < "31/8/2015", 3, year),
         year = ifelse(date > "1/9/2015" & date < "31/8/2016", 4, year),
         year = ifelse(date > "1/9/2016" & date < "31/8/2017", 5, year))
```

However, I keep getting the following error message:
"Error in date < "1/9/2012" : comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types"

Comment: You could create groupings and then do a histogram for each year or find the count of individuals per year, percentages, etc. It's difficult to tell you anything if there is no example code to use.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my post with a code.

Comment: To add to my answer below, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get some extra pointers on putting up example code. It would help to have some data to work with (for example using `dput` or randomly generating some similar data as I've tried to do). There's still uncertainty about what your data looks like, and whether my solution will work on it, as the dates in your dataframe might be formatted in a number of confusing ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to change, and would make good use of the `lubridate` package.

A couple of points to note first:

- The error message is because you've entered a character variable as the date and it doesn't know it's a date. Using `lubridate`'s `dmy()` function it will detect the **d**ay, **m**onth and **y**ear of the character string and turn it into a date object, comparable using < and >
- when using multiple `ifelse` statements, I think it struggles to do these sequentially within a single `mutate` call. One solution would be to nest them, so that within the first `ifelse` it calls the second one in the place of `year`, and within the second call the third etc. But there's a much tidier way of doing it with `case_when` in `dplyr`.

In the example here I've created some random sample dates, which are already in date format. In your dataframe they *probably* will be character strings, so the extra line there will help you turn them into dates:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# randomly generate some dates, starting from September 2012
d1 <- dmy("1/09/2012")
df <- tibble(date = d1 + runif(100, 0, 1500))

# add the 'year' column
df %>%
  # Not needed in this example, as column already formatted as date
  # mutate(date = dmy(date)) %>% 
  mutate(year = case_when(
         date < dmy("1/9/2013") ~ 1,
         date >= dmy("1/9/2013") & date <= dmy("31/8/2014") ~ 2,
         date >= dmy("1/9/2014") & date <= dmy("31/8/2015") ~ 3,
         date >= dmy("1/9/2015") & date <= dmy("31/8/2016") ~ 4,
         date >= dmy("1/9/2016") & date <= dmy("31/8/2017") ~ 5
         ))
```